# bitcoind failed to install on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, apt, bitcoind

i was previously using ubuntu 10.04 and i tried to install `bitcoind`. this failed and i upgraded to ubuntu 12.04. when i run `bitcoind` it still doesn't work:

```
$ bitcoind    
************************
EXCEPTION: 11DbException       
Db::open: Invalid argument       
bitcoin in AppInit()       

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'DbException'
  what():  Db::open: Invalid argument
Aborted (core dumped)
```

also trying to install again does not work:

```
$ sudo apt-get install bitcoind
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bitcoind
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 981 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,873 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu/ precise/main bitcoind amd64 0.8.5-precise1 [981 kB]
Fetched 981 kB in 7s (130 kB/s)                                                                                               
(Reading database ... 222704 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking bitcoind (from .../bitcoind_0.8.5-precise1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/bitcoind_0.8.5-precise1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bitcoind', which is also in package bitcoin 0.3.24-ppa2~lucid
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/bitcoind_0.8.5-precise1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

how can i get `bitcoind` working? i don't mind uninstalling and reinstalling if that is what it takes...

**update 1**

i just tried removing the package and installing again, but still no luck:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge bitcoind
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package bitcoind is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get install bitcoind
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bitcoind
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 981 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,873 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bitcoin/bitcoin/ubuntu/ precise/main bitcoind amd64 0.8.5-precise1 [981 kB]
Fetched 981 kB in 7s (136 kB/s)                                                                                               
(Reading database ... 222704 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking bitcoind (from .../bitcoind_0.8.5-precise1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/bitcoind_0.8.5-precise1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bitcoind', which is also in package bitcoin 0.3.24-ppa2~lucid
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/bitcoind_0.8.5-precise1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the end this was the solution:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/bitcoind_0.8.5-precise1_amd64.deb
```